# Fetching object JSON array using JSON_QUERY in MariaDB

Tags: json, mariadb, json-query

How do I access the value of a object property, inside an array, using `JSON_QUERY` in MariaDB? I have a JSON field with following data, and want to access the value of the `section` property.

```
[
  [
    {"section": "search"}
  ]
]
```

The following SQL is returning `NULL`

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY('[[{"section": "search"}]]', '$[0][0].section') FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else having the same issue, you have to use `JSON_VALUE` for accessing scalar values. The following query gives the expected result.

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE'[[{"section": "search"}]]', '$[0][0].section') FROM mytable;
```

[JSON_QUERY vs JSON_VALUE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/differences-between-json_query-and-json_value/)